# Neural network weights adjustment by the user ratings

Tags: artificial-intelligence, recommendation-engine, neural-network

im really new to NN, and im trying to implement it in my recommendation system that gives users recommendations on user similarities.
The thing is that im having 4 different similarities of users by different parameters, and im using weights to make the importance of each similarity in total similarity.

region similarity = 0.5, weightRegion=0.6

interests similarity = 0.3, weightInterest=0.8

education similarity = 0.75, weightEducation=1.1

positions similarity = 0.6, weightPositions=1.5

so calculating total similarity will be multiplied sum divided by sum of the weights: (0.5*0.6+0.3*0.8+0.75*1.1+0.6*1.5)/4
//im dividing by sum of weights to put parameter in {0..1} 
So the thing is i need to control those weights by the user rating (user clicks rating from 1 to 10 and weights r corrected)

I've built such NN:
[image: Neural Network]

So what im doing is:
n=0.25 (learning k);
rating=0.7 (that is my 7 rating);

net5=x1*w15+x2*w25+x3*w35+x4*w45;

out5=1/(1-pow(e,-net5));

real=out5*(1+1-rating);

err=out5*(1-out5)*(real-out5);

w15n=w15+err*n*x1;

w25n=w25+err*n*x2;

w35n=w35+err*n*x3;

w45n=w45+err*n*x4;

(im sry for code formatting, it kept saying its not properly formatted)

What am I doing wrong? cause results of such correcting arent good at all.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you make a NN with just one layer??? This way you can only get linear separation functions.

Comment: can u explain to me example of multilayered NN for this problem?
i just cant realize where i will get weights and parameters for other layers.

Comment: NN are all about the structure. The more complex your problem is, the more layers you will need to get a good result. The parameter of the layer are learned using an algorithm called: Backpropagation. You need a classified sample to use it.

Comment: i know backpropagation and im using it above, i do recompute weights, but i cant get this process for multiple layers, cause here i just use weights as my weights i put and input numbers as similarities. what weights should i use in the second layer? for example

Comment: So you dont know backpropagation. The Input to the last layer is always the difference of what you got and what you want.

Comment: Can u show it on my example? im calculating the real(what i want) output as an output multiplied by (1 + 1 - rating), and then im calculating the error on which i recalculate my weights, whats wrong?

Comment: http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/Backprop/backprop.html

Comment: Any reason you don't use the 4 similarity metrics to build an ensemble and then use that with standard collaborative filtering?

Comment: Steve, thats exactly what im doing, but i need to weight each metric, as parameters are not the same by importance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going the wrong way. Backpropagation isn't a good choice for this type of learning (somehow incremental learning).
To use backpropagation you need some data, say 1000 data where **different types of similaritiy (input)** and the **True Similarity (output)** are given. Then weights will update and update until error rate comes down. And besides you need test data set too that will make you sure the result network will do good even for similarity values it didn't see during training.

Comment: Got it after implementing this :)
So what would you propose for such type of learning?

Comment: I think reinforcement learning might be a good idea but I don't know much about it.